# Can I restart ActiveMQ without having to restart Mule?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

We have ActiveMQ and mySQL installed on a separate server to our Mule ESB. When the JMS connection drops out, it restarts, but we lose the link.

I'm wondering if i've missed something obvious in a settings file here, but is it possible to not have to restart the Mule server as well as the ActiveMQ server? If I restart or lose connection to ActiveMQ, it loses the link until I restart the mule server.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use reconnect strategy in this case.

Refer to the following link for Mule Reconnect Strategy and how to configure it.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/reconnection-strategy-reference

Hope this helps.